# Connection to SQL Server throws exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a task where I need to write a simple application to process some data from SQL Server. The process is working with dummy data, but I just can't connect to the server to get the valid data.

I have a code like this:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Server=----;Database=----;User ID=----;Password=*******";

string field1, field2;    

try
{
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open();

        using (IDbCommand dbcmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * from [---].[dbo].[Components]";
            dbcmd.CommandText = sql;

            using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    field1 = (string)reader["field1"];
                    field2 = (string)reader["field2"];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failure");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

My problem is, that if I run this code in a simple C# application, it works, no problem, but when I try to use it in the Xamarin application, the `Connection.Open()` throws an exception with the message:

> server does not exist or connection refused

And here it is my problem, I don't really know why this happenes, when I run it as an app. The problem shows up even in android emulator, which theoretically uses the same network as the c# application which works.

Do I need to change options in the app, or the problems is at the server side?

I know that it's not the best idea to connect directly, but the app will be used internally on a secured network, so that this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your emulator is connected to the same network? If yes, did you check that IP of your SQL server can be reached from the emulator? Also SQL port.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android emulator does not set correct DNS network parameters, so your application is not able to resolve the domain name of your SQL server.

So in your connection string try setting the IP address of SQL server instead of domain name.

```
string ConnectionString = @"Server=192.168.XXX.XXX;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword";
```